# Different array result in from same Javascript(SAP UI5) code

Tags: javascript, arrays, sapui5

> I am using cachebuster to determine the changes file in the
>   application structure.

**Code that in the javascript file**

[image: Code that in the javascript file]

**Array  result which doesnt work:**

[image: Array result which doesnt work]

**Array  result which works**

[image: Array result which works]

I am not sure why the responses are different for the same piece of the code, the file which is being extracted looks similar in both the ajax calls. Now please help me in unwrapping the result which doesnt work into a array like it looks in working result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between the 2 responses was the working one was responding with current data type as JSON, where the issue with non working code is the response was send back with data type of text/html. I used **JSON.parse** on the response before being passed on to the next piece of code which resolved the issue i had.

var aChangeFilesPaths = Object.keys(**JSON.parse**(oCachebusterContent));

[image]

Thanks all.